# Can I change the position of chrome extension using default action popup appears in?

Tags: reactjs, browser, google-chrome-extension

When I click on the icon to open the extension, I want it to appear a little lower on the screen than it does now. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Not possible. You can only open a separate window using chrome.windows.create. Well, if you really want you could move the standard popup using low-level system API in an external utility invoked via nativeMessaging...

Comment: That is what I was afraid you would say, I saw one other response from a long time ago that said the same thing and was hoping maybe this had been updated. Thank you. I will consider this closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not possible. You can only open a separate window using chrome.windows.create. >Well, if you really want you could move the standard popup using low-level system >API in an external utility invoked via nativeMessaging... – wOxxOm 14 hours ago

Thanks W0xx0m for the quick answer.